# List Column Formula

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to get a column value like SHAREPOINT[YYYY]001 and YYYY represents current year and 001 will increment on each submission of the list. SHAREPOINT will be constant term.

Answer (score 0):

```
="SHAREPOINT" & TEXT([Created],"YYYY") & TEXT([ID],"000")
```

Only one issue; that ID column is **is 0 in Formulas in newly created items** so requires a trigger to be set to the correct value, with either a Workflow or some code.

See: [Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)